# How to create data properties in the App.vue file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm new at Vue CLI 3. I just created a new project using `vue create` and tried to add some `data`properties in the `export default`section of the `App.vue`file using the syntax of the [Vue.js tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering),

```js
  data: { 
    people: ["Mary", "Lluis", "Pepe"]
  }
```

But it doesn't work an error arises that says `data property must be a function`. I tried instead,

```js
  data: function() { 
    people: ["Mary", "Lluis", "Pepe"]
  }
```

But it doesn't work neither. Do you know how I should do it and why there's such a difference in syntax with the [Vue.js Tutorial](https://vuejs.org/)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the value

```
 data: function() { 
   return {
     people: ["Mary", "Lluis", "Pepe"]
   }
 }
```

Comment: It works! I'd like to know why it needs a function instead of ´data: { }´ as in the vue.js official tutorial.

Comment: @A.Amengual, you can read about it here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function